# why the kafka lag is suddenly down to zero even though it is consuming the records?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using the Flink to forward the records from source to destination.
The source and sink is kafka so the dataflow is as below.

```
Kafka -> Flink -> Kafka
```

When I monitored the `consumer lag` in the dashboard, the pattern looks like going steadily up and then suddenly going to vertically down to almost zero in certain time as a picture below.

I know that the concept of the Kafka lag. But I don't understand why the lag is still increasing during the more than half of hour even though the Flink consumed the records without delay.

The checkpoint of the Flink is set to `500ms`, so I think that the Kafka lag should be reduced every 500ms or similar interval. But the lag is reduced in almost one hour in my case.

I understand what the lag is meaning but I am not sure that why the lag is going to down for long time even though the message is consumed without delay.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Flink is committing offsets in batches? Meanwhile, there's still a producer sending new events? Delay in consumption isn't really relevant for lag calculations, only committed offsets

Comment: How do I know that my flink commits the offset in batch? I did not use flink batch mode. I know that committing occurs every checkpoint in Flink.

Answer (score 0):

Flink commits offsets when checkpoints are completed, as explained on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#consumer-offset-committing

It would be good to verify that your checkpoints are indeed completing. Looking at your graph, it looks like this is only happening every 30/45 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already checked that my checkpoint have been completed within 1000 ms. My checkpoint is configured to 500ms and checkpoint timeout is set to 1 min. I don't fully understand such case. In Flink, there is no backpressure and the records are observed as same number of records of the input.